# Shopify GraphQL Checkout Create Mutation

Tags: graphql, shopify

I cannot create a checkout with Shopify's Graphql API

I am literally copying the example from this page in [Shopify's Checkout Guide](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/guides/checkout-guide) and pasting it into Shopify's GraphiQL App installed on the store where I am trying to create the checkout.

This is my mutation, where the only thing I changed was the `variantId` so it matches one on my store:

```
mutation {
  checkoutCreate(input: {
    lineItems: [{ variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/46037988422", quantity: 1 }]
  }) {
    checkout {
       id
       webUrl
       lineItems(first: 5) {
         edges {
           node {
             title
             quantity
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response I'm getting from Shopify:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field 'checkoutCreate' doesn't exist on type 'Mutation'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "mutation",
        "checkoutCreate"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "undefinedField",
        "typeName": "Mutation",
        "fieldName": "checkoutCreate"
      }
    }
```

The weird thing is that obviously `checkoutCreate` IS a mutation, according to Shopify. [See the link to the page here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/reference/mutation/checkoutcreate)

Then I noticed, that the mutation on that page is different. So I'm trying that version, without a `variable` like this:

```
mutation checkoutCreate(input: {
    lineItems: [{ variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/46037988422", quantity: 1 }]
  }) {
    checkout {
      id
    }
    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
}
```

And now the error I'm getting back is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Parse error on \"input\" (INPUT) at [1, 25]",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally I tried this version with a variable and it also failed:

```
mutation checkoutCreate($input: CheckoutCreateInput!) {
  checkoutCreate(input: $input) {
    checkout {
      id
    }
    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}

{
  "input": {
    lineItems: [{ variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/46037988422", quantity: 1 }]
  }
}
```

The error here was:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Parse error on \"input\" (STRING) at [15, 3]",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 15,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

On top of all this, Shopify has interactive docs in their GraphiQL App.. and it does NOT list checkoutCreate as an available mutation. See this screenshot: https://nimb.ws/af4iHx

Comment: I am facing the same Issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your input is parsed as JSON, so try putting quotes even around the nested properties of your mutation variables when testing.

```
    {
      "input": {
        "lineItems": [{ "variantId": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/46037988422", 
                    "quantity": 1 }]
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mutations that complete checkouts are only available for sales channels. These apps must be public. So it might not work if you are creating a private app.

https://shopify.dev/tutorials/create-a-checkout-with-storefront-api
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-a-public-app-with-oauth#turn-an-app-into-a-sales-channel

Answer (score 0):

When you do the mutation in the Shopify GraphQl Explorer make sure you've selected the mutation below the explorer window, I've seen that mainly causes the the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJOSC.png)

Make sure before working on mutation you select mutation from the dropdown and click on the plus icon. It happens when the query is selected and you paste mutation query and vice versa.